# No ACPI video bus was found

Tags: boot, live-usb, 16.04, cd-image

Today, when I turned on my computer, I got a message on a black screen every time it rebooted, which was `"No ACPI video bus was found"`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)